# N nested for loops in a python

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I want N number of nested for loops, the last for loop should have `number += 1` while everything else should have `push(move)` and should end with a `undo()` I saw a way to solve in another language that said something about recursion.

The following example if for 5 for loops:

```
number = 0
for move in all_legal_moves():
    push(move)
    for move2 in all_legal_moves():
        push(move2)
        for move3 in all_legal_moves():
            push(move3)
            for move4 in all_legal_moves():
                push(move4)
                for move5 in all_legal_moves():
                    number += 1
                undo()
            undo()
        undo()
    undo()
```

I want a function that takes the depth (the number of nested for loops (N)) and return `number`. I would prefer an answer that doesn't imports any libraries

Comment: Have you looked at recursion yourself at all? Can you share your own attempt at making this a recursive function? Or is your question how to write a recursive function at all? Or even a function at all?

Comment: i think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65512563/633183) to be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is simply a function keeps calling itself until it meets certain condition. You can learn more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/). I think in this case you can make the code above recursive by having it either `push` + go to another recursion level + `undo` or `number += 1` by checking if the current loop level (`level` in the code below) is equal to `N` (`max_level` in the code below)

```
number = 0

def moves(level, max_level):
    global number
    if level < max_level:
        for move in all_legal_moves():
            push(move)
            moves(level + 1, max_level)
            undo()
    else:
        number += 1


moves(move, 1, 5)
print('Number of possible moves:', number)
```

Or if you don't want to have `number` as a global variable, you can make the function return the number of possible iterations instead

```
def moves(level, max_level):
    number = 0
    if level < max_level:
        for move in all_legal_moves():
            push(move)
            number += moves(level + 1, max_level)
            undo()
    else:
        number += 1
    return number

number_of_possible_moves = moves(move, 1, 5)
print('Number of possible moves', number_of_possible_moves)
```

Comment: what should i give for the ```move``` parameter? and the inner calling should be ```moves(move, level + 1, max_level)``` right

Comment: I removed the ```move``` parameter and it works now thanks!

Comment: Oh right, I changed the function parameters from 2 to 3 parameters but I haven't changed it where it's being called. Yeah removing `move` parameter should work. Thanks for point out!

Comment: oh and ```number_of_moves(depth, level=0)```  might be a better way. In the function ```number += number_of_moves(depth, level+1)``` and for calling the function ```number_of_possible_moves = number_of_moves(3)``` would be easier, not a big deal but still and thanks a lot